# SQL Server CE not installing properly on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have a software suite that runs on Windows Mobile. In the process of supporting a new Honeywell handheld, I've run into some problems with SQL Server CE. I use my normal cabs (`sqlce.wce5.armv4i.CAB`, and `sqlce.dev.enu.ppc.wce4.armv4.CAB`) which normally work fine, but my software gets the following error:

> File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3', or one of its dependencies, was not found

The device runs Windows Mobile 6.5 Build 21915, by the way.

I read tons of forum pages about this issue, and followed their advice to use the cabs from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500`. I've tried every combination of cabs for different processor types from there, yet nothing works. Often there will be a folder in Program Files with the correct dlls, but if I look in the registry, the keys listed on this page http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/sql-compact-35-wince50-102180.aspx do not appear.

If I deploy from Visual Studio 2008, SQL installs perfectly, and the registry keys are there. I've looked at the output from Visual studio, found the precise cabs it installs, ran them, and still have no luck. I'm hoping someone here has some ideas that might lead me down the right path.

Edit: I've also followed these instructions with no luck http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13kw2t64%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across a problem like this, here's how I managed to fix it after hours of effort:
In the Windows folder there is a utility called wceload.exe. Use the device's command prompt to install cabs with this utility, it should install them properly.